# CSS/HTML - How can I center something when auto-margin does not seem to work?

Tags: html, css

This is part of the CSS for my menu:

```
ul {
    text-align: left;
    display: inline;
    margin: auto;
    width: 50%;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    list-style: none;
}
```

I have tried `auto-margin left and right`. All of the methods I have tried have never resulted in the entire page being center with itself.

Here is what I have done with the main 'box' that is under the above menu.

```
.box {
    margin: auto;
    width: 50%;
    padding: 20px;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    word-break: break-all;
}
```

Full page source is at: https://pastebin.com/56HbfaGM

What also bothers me is that different browsers show different results.

I have not done much with HTML/CSS in years so sorry if this is super basic of a problem.

I just simply want to know some more holistic methods of centering.

Comment: Welcome back to CSS! :D Check out flexbox, it is soooo nice!
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: Well that's something new! Looks like it could help center the entire page!

Comment: Do you want to centre it both vertically and horizontally?

Answer (score 1):

You can't center using `margin: 0 auto` if your element is `position: fixed`. And you can't use `margin: 0 auto` on an `inline` element.

Another problem you have is that the `ul` element has padding on its left side. You'll want to remove that to center things correctly.

And your final problem is even if you successfully center the `ul` element, it won't *look* centered because there'll be a portion of the element not filled with list items depending on the width of the screen since the background is transparent. You can fix that by either adding `background: #A4A4A4` to give the `ul` element a solid background matching the `li` elements, or you can center the `li` elements by using `text-align: center` on the `ul` element.

The following is an example of centering a fixed element correctly, along with centering the list items.

```
ul {
  text-align: center;
  display: inline;
  padding: 0;
  width: 50%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  margin: 0 0 0 -25%;
  list-style: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

IIRC, you can't use auto without a defined width. Also, it's `margin:0 auto;`, though that might not matter with html5's lack of strictness.

Comment: `margin: 0 auto` and `margin: auto` are both valid CSS and will both horizontally center block-level elements.

Answer (score 0):

The right way is use margin:0 auto; below I've made two ways to center a box.

HTML

```
<!-- Margin box -->
<div class="container">
  <div class="box-centered">

  </div>
</div>

<br>

<!-- Flexbox box -->
<div class="Aligner">
  <div class="Aligner-item"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
/* Margin:auto way */

.container {
  width: 100%;
}
.box-centered {
  width: 50%;
  height: 300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: red;
}

/* Flexbox way */
.Aligner {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.Aligner-item {
  width: 50%;
  height: 300px;
  background: blue
}
```

Here the example in jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/1h0f74qb/

Hope this can help you.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of **display: inline**, you could use **display: flex**:

```
ul{
   ...
   display: flex;
   align-content: center;
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

depends on how you need to center the item.

`display: flex`, with `align-items:center`

Simple example using flex box in HTML/CSS

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
<style>
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #ccc;
}</style>
</head>
<body>

<h1>This is a Heading</h1>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>

</body>
</html>
```